# Searching for outermost parentheses using Python regex

Tags: python, regex, string

Apologies for the ambiguous title, but I don't know how to word my problem in such a way that makes sense in a single sentence.

So I have some simple regex code to extract code between brackets.

```
^.*\((.*)\).*
```

This successfully works in Python with the following code.

```
m = re.search( "^.*\((.*)\).*" ,input)
if m:
    print(m.groups()[0])
```

My problem occurs when a closing bracket `)` may be inside the outermost brackets. For example, my current code when given

```
nsfnje (19(33)22) sfssf
```

as an input would return

```
19(33
```

but I would like it to return.

```
19(33)22
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> input = "nsfnje (19(33)22) sfssf"
>>> re.search( "\((.*)\)" ,input).group(1)
'19(33)22'
```

Note that this searches for outermost parentheses, even if they are unbalanced (e.g. `"(1(2)))))"`). It is not possible to search for balanced parentheses using a single standard regular expression. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15597782/367273).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex) has more details on why regexes don't work for general nesting and some alternative approaches if you do need it.

Comment: If you want to do the same with curly braces simply replace `\(` with `{` and `\)` with `}`: `re.search("{(.*)}", text, re.S).group(1)`. Also, to make `.` match line breaks, `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` is required: `re.search("\((.*)\)", text, re.DOTALL).group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You code does not give `19(33`, it gives `33)22`.

The problem is that the `^.*` at the start of your regex matches all the way up to the *last* `(` in the string, whereas you actually want to match *from* the *first* `(` in the string.

If you just want what is within the outermost brackets, then remove the `.*` at the start of your regex, and you may as well remove the ending `.*` also as it similarly serves no purpose.

```
"\((.*)\)"
```

If you want the match of the whole line/string as well as what is within the brackets, then make the first `*` match lazily by adding a `?`

```
"^.*?\((.*)\).*"
```

or better, use

```
"^[^(]*\((.*)\).*"
```